# Fill in missing dates for a vacation schedule

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, date

Have an issue that has been driving me nuts for the past week and can't seem to get my head around it.

I have a stored procedure that grabs a bunch of vacation requests from our scheduling system. I need to now get each day that the individual has requested into a single row to pivot and plot in excel at the request of the user.

[image: SourceTable]

This is the end result I am looking for in a SQL Table

[image: FinalProd]

Any help is appreciated, already have a `datedimension` table created, tried using `CTE` and another attempt using outer apply but at this point I am spinning my wheels.

UPDATE:  Calendar Table

This is the table (Calendar Table) I am using - Populated with 30 years of dates

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DateDimension](
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Day] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [DaySuffix] [char](2) NOT NULL,
    [Weekday] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [WeekDayName] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [IsWeekend] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsHoliday] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [HolidayText] [varchar](64) SPARSE  NULL,
    [DOWInMonth] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [DayOfYear] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [WeekOfMonth] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [WeekOfYear] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [ISOWeekOfYear] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Month] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [MonthName] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Quarter] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [QuarterName] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [Year] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MMYYYY] [char](6) NOT NULL,
    [MonthYear] [char](7) NOT NULL,
    [FirstDayOfMonth] [date] NOT NULL,
    [LastDayOfMonth] [date] NOT NULL,
    [FirstDayOfQuarter] [date] NOT NULL,
    [LastDayOfQuarter] [date] NOT NULL,
    [FirstDayOfYear] [date] NOT NULL,
    [LastDayOfYear] [date] NOT NULL,
    [FirstDayOfNextMonth] [date] NOT NULL,
    [FirstDayOfNextYear] [date] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: The best way long term is to use a [calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/). For better service, read this meta post: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql).

Comment: Thanks Erik,  I have a calendar table, went down this road a bit too.

Struggling with how I get the data into the format I need, joining the calendar table and vacation table together.  Knowing that multiple people may be requesting the same day off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you can get your desired result by dates generation during run-time with `CROSS APPLY` (as per [Tony Hinkle's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/247196/185080)). in performance point of view it's better to use calendar table. Good that you already have it.

This is what expected part of the question (as per Erik Darling [comment](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)):

```
Create table #Vacation 
(Requestor varchar(10),
SchCode varchar(10),
ReqLine int,
FromDate datetime,
ToDate datetime,
Comment varchar (100)  )
go


Insert into #Vacation
values
('Smith', 'V12', 1, '2019-09-01', '2019-09-03', 'Vacation Request')
go


Create table #DateDimension
(
    [Date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Day] [tinyint] NOT NULL
)
go

Insert into #DateDimension 
values 
('2019-09-01', 1),
('2019-09-02', 2),
('2019-09-03', 3),
('2019-09-04', 4),
('2019-09-05', 5)
go


--Drop Table #Vacation;
--Drop table #DateDimension;
```

You can get desired result utilizing `datedimension` table, as follows:

```
select  d.Date,
        s.Requestor,
        s.SchCode
from #Vacation as s
        left join #DateDimension as d 
            on d.Date >= s.FromDate and d.Date <= s.ToDate
```

Comment: Thanks! this is all great information, tested this as well and it worked for what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a `CROSS APPLY` that will generate the dates.

```
SELECT m.requestor, m.schedcode, o.Date FROM mockup m
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, m.fromdate, m.enddate) + 1)
        Date = DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY a.object_id) - 1, m.fromdate)
        FROM    sys.all_objects a
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b
) AS o
```

Props to GarethD's answer at [Get all dates between two dates in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23290454/get-all-dates-between-two-dates-in-sql-server) for the date generating code.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you, and thanks to the community for a quick answer!

Comment: Never use `TOP` without an `ORDER BY`. Top according to which order?

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case.  It is just pulling some random rows to be able to use ROW_NUMBER().